# ios applications crashes on the start after updating to new version from apple store

Tags: ios, react-native

I have uploaded a new version of my app to the apple store and when users tried to update it to the new one, it crashes on the start with some users having ios 14.0 , but when they reinstall the app and download it, it works without crashing.
so what the reasons behind the crash, how to produce the issue, and how to solve it?

**beside note:**

I added react-native-video package.

the app is working fine on simulator and testfight.

all the previous version was uploaded with this version of cocoapods: 1.8.4

And this new one I uploaded it with the updated version cocoapods: 1.10.0

is it may be the reason of the crash?

*the application is built with react native.*

Comment: It is impossible to state the cause without more information. You need to show crash details; an exception message, a symbolicated stack trace and the relevant code. When an app is upgraded the code is replaced but the contents of the data directories is untouched.  It seems likely that your new version is crashing when it reads the old data, but that is just a guess. You should always test upgrading your new version on a device with the old version installed before releasing it